# How run shell script from R environment

Tags: r

I have raw micro-array expression data files with extension .CEL, but for few files the extension is somehow \ .CEL (ie. name space dot CEL). I have made a simple shell script that replaces file names correctly on ubuntu terminal, but I do not have any idea of using it in R environment. I have even tried it using `system()` command to execute shell script, but did not work for me.

Shell Script I have written is as follows:

```
for file in *.CEL; 
do mv "$file" "${file//[[:space:]]}";
done
```

Comment: How about something like: `f <- list.files('/path/containing/files', patt='\\.CEL', full.names=TRUE); file.rename(f, sub(' \\.CEL', 'replacement', f))`, where `replacement` is the string you want to replace `.CEL` with. See `?list.files` and `?file.rename` for more details.

Comment: What does "did not work for me" mean? Error messages? Nothing happened What? `system` **is** the way to run shell scripts from R. So what did you do exactly, what was the error?

Comment: Thanks for the help sebastian. Barry, thanks for the concern, and the error was :::::Error: unexpected string constant in "system("for file in *.CEL; do mv "$file" "". Anyway, I have solved the problem.